# Ember : TypeError: Invalid Fullname, expected: 'type:name' got: route

Tags: ember.js

I am getting the following error when i am trying to access localhost:4200 in ember. I could go to other routes but not this route. And there is no clear error log. Please help me

```
TypeError: Invalid Fullname, expected: 'type:name' got: route:
at Registry.validateFullName (ember.debug.js:2286)
at Container.lookup (ember.debug.js:1258)
at Class.lookup (ember.debug.js:34323)
at C.getHandler (ember.debug.js:29862)
at C.fetchHandler (ember.debug.js:48543)
at C.get (ember.debug.js:48708)
at C.becomeResolved (ember.debug.js:48679)
at calculatePostTransitionState (ember.debug.js:30387)
at Class._hydrateUnsuppliedQueryParams (ember.debug.js:30099)
at Class._prepareQueryParams (ember.debug.js:30030)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to injecting an invalid service. I had the same issue when upgrading from Ember v2.6.3 to v2.7.0.

`store: Ember.inject.service('store:user')` stopped working and I had to use `store: Ember.inject.service('store')` inside my service.